# How to incorporate ATR as TP and SL?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to use the ATR (times a multiplier) to exit either the TP or SL. I came up with what I thought was the correct reasoning, but the backtester doesn't close the trades: it simply flip flops from long to short as if the following entry signal were the close signal. I've got my entry condition sorted and it works.

With regards to my TP or SL, I have this code:

```
//Define the ATR length
atrLength = 14`

// Calculate the ATR
atr = ta.atr(atrLength)`

// Define the stop loss level
stopLoss = close - (atr * 2)`

// Define the take profit level
takeProfit = close + (atr * 4)`

// Check if the conditions are met
condition1 = ema10 > ema30
condition2 = ta.crossover(close, ema30)`

if condition1 and condition2
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
else
    if ema10 < ema30 and ta.crossunder(close, ema30)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `strategy.exit()` function to exit a trade based on some price level.

You can use the `limit` argument of the `strategy.exit()` for the take profit price and `stop` for the stop loss price.

The `limit` and `stop` arguments of the `strategy.entry()` function are for limit orders.

**strategy.entry()**

```
strategy.entry(id, direction, qty, limit, stop, oca_name, oca_type, comment, alert_message) → void
```

> ***limit (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Limit price of the
> order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'limit', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.
>
> ***stop (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Stop price of the
> order. If it is specified, the order type is either 'stop', or
> 'stop-limit'. 'NaN' should be specified for any other order type.

**strategy.exit**

```
strategy.exit(id, from_entry, qty, qty_percent, profit, limit, loss, stop, trail_price, trail_points, trail_offset, oca_name, comment, comment_profit, comment_loss, comment_trailing, alert_message, alert_profit, alert_loss, alert_trailing) → void
```

> ***limit (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Profit target
> (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a limit order is
> placed to exit market position at the specified price (or better).
> Priority of the parameter 'limit' is higher than priority of the
> parameter 'profit' ('limit' is used instead of 'profit', if its value
> is not 'NaN'). The default value is 'NaN'.
>
> ***stop (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a
> specific price). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit
> market position at the specified price (or worse). Priority of the
> parameter 'stop' is higher than priority of the parameter 'loss'
> ('stop' is used instead of 'loss', if its value is not 'NaN'). The
> default value is 'NaN'.

Answer (score 0):

In Pinescript, your code is evaluated on each bar.
So when the condition1 and condition2 are met, on each bar, your strategy.entry is updated, and so your stoploss and takeprofit.
This way, you entry with the condition1 and condition2 will never hit your SL or TP.
Then, when the conditions change, you enter a short, and entering a short will close your long (if a long is already on).

You should add a test not to update your entry long if a long is already on.

You can do this with strategy.position_size which will give you 0 if there is no market position, a >0 value if the market position is long and a value <0 if the market position is short.

So you could change your condition with :

```
if strategy.position_size==0
    if condition1 and condition2
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
    else
        if ema10 < ema30 and ta.crossunder(close, ema30)
            strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
```

Be carefull, with this code, once you enter a long or a short, you will not have new enter order until your SL or TP is hit.

Comment: Thank you. I added that. While it loads, it only gives me one trade which hasn't supposedly yet closed.

This is the full code, any idea what's wrong?

https://pastebin.com/9UVyVh3M

Comment: If my answer helps you understand how your code behave, please accept the answer and post a new one with your new code (it is forbiden to ask new questions in comments), you will get help